# C# + Visio 2007 integration

Tags: c#, visio

I am using Visio 2007 in order to draw the organization chart.
Everything is working fine, but i have a problem on how to access and set the properties of the shape object in the below namespace

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It may help not only you but others too.. :)

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio
Public Class VisioMain

```
Dim currentStencil As Document
Dim currentPage As Page

Private Sub VisioMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    currentPage = DC.Document.Pages(1)
    SetLandscape(currentPage)

    currentStencil = DC.Document.Application.Documents.OpenEx("Rack-mounted Equipment (US units).VSS", VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked)

    Dim stencilWindow As Window
    stencilWindow = currentPage.Document.OpenStencilWindow
    stencilWindow.Activate()
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    ''Code to get individual property of Shape...........!
    For Each objShape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape In currentPage.Shapes
        TextBox1.Text = objShape.Cells("Prop.Height").ResultStr("text")
    Next

    ''.............!

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

Visio makes extensive use of something called a cell which is similar to excel cells.
To get a cell reference from a shape:

```
Visio.Cell aCell = shape1.Cells("Prop.XXXX");
```

XXXX is the name of the property.
To get the value of the cell:

```
aCell.FormulaU
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly? Here is how I set the text property of a shape.

```
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

[...] (some code)

Visio.Shape shape1 = page.Drop(currentStencil.Masters["Start/End"], 1.50, 1.50);
shape1.Text = "John";
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. But what i exactly need is set the Custom properties of the shape, other than the text property.